# flutter run on ios emulator

Tags: xcode, flutter

Error output from Xcode build:
↳
2022-06-08 15:01:02.170 xcodebuild[77786:964621] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier
Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in
com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-06-08 15:01:02.171 xcodebuild[77786:964621] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier
Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in
com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
Writing result bundle at path:
/var/folders/gd/tsbhn_r55f1bzmqmjwj99zzw0000gn/T/flutter_tools.mQ0a7x/flutter_ios_build_temp_dir7medmZ/temporary_xcresult_bundle

```
Failed to package /Users/thura/Project_studio/bliss.
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Using new build system
note: Planning
note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in dependency order
/Users/thura/Project_studio/bliss/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but
the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.5.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')

Result bundle written to path:
    /var/folders/gd/tsbhn_r55f1bzmqmjwj99zzw0000gn/T/flutter_tools.mQ0a7x/flutter_ios_build_temp_dir7medmZ/temporary_xcresult_bundle
```

Answer (score 1):

"Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code" may come from many different sources.

Common ways to fix it:

- Delete Derived Datas
- Restart your Mac
- `flutter clean` + `flutter pub get`
- in ios folder:  `pod deintegrate` + `pod install`

Comment: thank you for your replay and i rebuilt my flutter project on xcode got an error [Error xcode_backend.sh: No such file or directory]

Comment: If you create a new project using `flutter create`, are you able to compile it ?